# Can't Select Bones or Bone Tips in Edit Mode

Tags: armature, bones

I recently downloaded Blender 2.8 and began working on a new model in this new version of Blender. I'm creating a skeleton for the mesh, but I'm unable to select the bones, or bone tips, in edit mode (not pose mode) to extrude from or move around. The only thing that works is clicking around the bone tip of the base bone, and doing that goes through selecting the bones in order of their hierarchy on the armature.

I'm not sure if it's just me, if there is an option I need to change, or if this is just a new change added to Blender, which is not a very effective new way way to go around edit bones within an armature.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem because I was following an old tutorial but the only way I could find was to be in edit mode when adding bones to keep one Amature hierarchy
Hope that helped?

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem when I was shading my figure, and then decided to try to alter the position after loading. I had to make sure I was in "Layout" and not "Modeling", "Animation" or "Shading". After selecting the bones, I could enter Pose Mode in addition to selecting other modes and using the bones